# Cannot resolve junit in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMwF0.png)

It gives me following error:

> **Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
>   Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog**

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am not able to even compile a simple application in the android studio.

I even don't know how to completely uninstall Android studio in Ubuntu.

Comment: "Can anyone help me with this problem?" -- either something is wrong with one (or both) of your `build.gradle` files, or Android Studio is unable to communicate with JCenter for some reason. "I even don't know how to completely uninstall Android studio in Ubuntu" -- delete the directory, and the peer `Android/` directory that it created.

Comment: remove the line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` from the build.gradle , that'd solve the problem!

Comment: Thank you. The error is gone but there is new one: FileNotFoundException: /home/ash/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_19.ini (Permission denied)

Comment: Did you install and/or run Android Studio as a different user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the below line from `build.gradle`:

> testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

and don't forget to `sync` again.

Comment: This was some time ago but I think this is not the best way on solving this problem. If you want to test things, you'll have to put jUnit back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes setu basak is right. I got the same error today without internet access (on my system)

I just commented the line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` from `build.gradle` and `sync`
and it worked.